# Error cannot resolve method setArguments()

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, float

Estoy tratando de pasar un valor `float` de un `fragment` a un `activity`, utilizando `Bundle`, pero cuando me indica error con el método `setArguments()`, lo coloca en rojo y me indica:

> cannot resolve method setArguments()

```
    float numis = (float) 2.11;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActMapa.class);
    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    bundle1.putFloat("dato_lat", numis);
    intent.setArguments();
```

Comment: Hola Armando para enviar datos a una Activity  no uses setArguments, solo agrega el bundle al Intent, intent.putExtras(bundle);

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas enviar valores o un `Bundle` mediante un `Intent` solo debes crear el `Bundle` y agregar los datos, al final define el bundle que deseas enviar en el `Intent` mediante `putExtras()`:

#### Enviar bundle a Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

---

El uso de `setArguments()` se recomienda para enviar un `bundle` pero hacia un `Fragment`:

#### Enviar bundle a Fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```